# How to compare string with const char*?

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
        string cmd;
        while(strcmp(cmd.c_str(),"exit")==0 && strcmp(cmd.c_str(),"\exit")==0)
        {
                cin>>cmd;
                cout<<cmd;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

I am stuck.

Comment: It's better to paste the code directly in the question

Comment: Also, it's cleaner if you use cmd.compare("exit") instead of strcmp(cms,c_str(),"exit")==0

You are writing C++ code.  Why not take advantage of it?

Comment: STL provides `operator==` for `const char*`, why not use that?

Comment: @Stephen: Actually, `std::string` isn't from that part of the standard library which evolved from the STL. Otherwise you're certainly right.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After fixing a couple of small bugs, this works on my machine:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

int main()
{
        std::string cmd;
        while( std::strcmp(cmd.c_str(),"exit")!=0
            && std::strcmp(cmd.c_str(),"\\exit")!=0)
        {
                std::cin>>cmd;
                std::cout<<cmd << '\n';
        }
        return 0;
}
```

However, I wonder why you want to use `std::strcmp()` at all. As you have just found out, it's not as easy to use as the `std::string` class. This

```
while(cmd!="exit" && cmd!="\\exit")
```

works just as well, is easier to understand, and thus easier to get right.

Comment: The OP may want to convert the input string to lowercase before comparing.  This allows user to type in "Exit" as well as "exit".  The terms to research are: `std::transform` and `tolower`.

Comment: There's also `strcasecmp` on Unixy (maybe Windows as well) systems, which ignores case.

Answer (score 20):

A `std::string` instance can be compared directly with a string literal using `!=` or `==` operators. This makes your comparison clearer.

Note that `\e` isn't a valid character escape, you need to double the `\` if you meant a literal `\\`.

```
while( cmd == "exit" && cmd == "\\exit" )
```

Obviously `cmd` can't be equal to two different strings at the same time, presumably you meant `!=`.

Also, consider whether `std::getline( std::cin, cmd )` is more appropriate than `std::cin >> cmd;`. In either case you should check for success of the read operation otherwise you may end in an infinite loop if the stream is closed or enters a failed state.

Personally I'd go with something like this, assuming that you want to echo the exit command as your code does.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

int main()
{
    std::string cmd;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, cmd))
    {
        std::cout << cmd << std::endl;
        if (cmd == "exit" || cmd == "\\exit")
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`strcmp` returns 0 when they are equal.  So I think you want != 0

Surely `strcmp` won't return 0 for both, because it can't be equal to both.

Also it looks like you have a backslash at the start of your string, you should escape that with a double backslash.

Answer (score 2):

The condition in your while will never evaluate to `true` because you're testing to check the cmd string is equal to `"exit"` **and** `"\\exit"`. One string can never be equals to two values at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem are the while conditions.

You probably would want do exit the loop when the user enters exit, so you should use:

```
while(strcmp(cmd.c_str(),"exit")!=0 && strcmp(cmd.c_str(),"\exit")!=0)
```

Answer (score -2):

Just a few things to keep in mind, i am reiterating some of the suggestions that are worth repeating while(1) times.

1. You are using C++, it is object oriented, i.e., Its best to combine together the data and the function that works on it. In this case use the string compare options provided by string class rather than strcmp.
2. There is a logic error in your program, well it will compile, but i am afraid thats not what you want. if ( a == x && a == y ) this will always be false, as a cannot be both equal to x and y unless x=y, in your case clearly x!=y.

Cheers,
Pavan