# compare const char * with strcmp

Tags: c++, char, constants, strcmp

I compare a `const char *` to a string and for some reason it always succeeds.

```
    if (std::strcmp(t->detectColor->name, "ghghjg") != 0) {
        printf("XXXXXXXXXXX\n");
        // check if it was allready a sequencer
        if (std::strcmp(t->className, "IM_SURE_IT_CANT_BE_THIS") != 0) {
          printf("what is going on?\n");
```

The detectColor name is always something like green or blue, and `t->className` is "ofxDTangibleBase" for example. Still it prints

```
XXXXXXXXXXX
what is going on?
```

in the console.
How can i get a valid compare?

Comment: Did you sleep well? Coming from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931704/how-to-compare-string-with-const-char It's quite a easy mistake.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/):

> Returns an integral value indicating the relationship between the
>   strings: **A zero value indicates that both strings are equal**. A value
>   greater than zero indicates that the first character that does not
>   match has a greater value in str1 than in str2; And a value less than
>   zero indicates the opposite.

Or said differently by [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp):

> **Return value**
>
> - Negative value if lhs is less than rhs.
> - 0​ if lhs is equal to rhs.
> - Positive value if lhs is greater than rhs.

So, in your code, `strcmp(t->detectColor->name, "ghghjg")` will return something different than 0. As a consequence, "XXXXXXXXXXX" will be printed.

You only have to change:

```
if (std::strcmp(t->detectColor->name, "ghghjg") != 0)
```

to

```
if (std::strcmp(t->detectColor->name, "ghghjg") == 0)
```

And the same for the other comparison.

Comment: use better cppreference for citations

Comment: @piotruś: Are you saying this citation is wrong? It looks fine to me, although perhaps it would be better to quote the C standard rather than some website.

Comment: @piotruś I have added your reference. I used cplusplus.com because they are often the first result on Google and do the job.

Comment: I just wanted to give an advice, cppreference is better source, in this case however citation is of course correct

Comment: Thanks man, didn't except comparing was so advanced in c++ :)

Comment: @clankill3r: In C++, you'd use `std::string` and compare with `==`. It's only complicated because you're using the C library for some reason.

Comment: @Mike Seymour what about comparing a const char * to a string? Also `==`? (I can't test now but i'm curious)

Comment: @clankill3r: Yes, you can also compare `std::string` with a C-style `const char*` string using `==`.

Answer (score 2):

`std::strcmp` returns 0 when strings are the same, and value less than 0 or greater than 0 when strings differ. So you might change your code for something like this:

```
if (std::strcmp(t->className, "IM_SURE_IT_CANT_BE_THIS") != 0) {
  printf("indeed, strings are different\n");
```

> Negative value if lhs is less than rhs. 
>   ​0​ if lhs is equal to rhs.
>   Positive value if lhs is greater than rhs.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp

---

**How can i get a valid compare?**

```
if (std::strcmp(t->className, "IM_SURE_IT_CANT_BE_THIS") == 0) {
      printf("strings are equal lexicographically\n");
```